# Web spider: [ValueError] No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: python, json, session, get

Recenetly I have been doing the web spider for fun. I want to learn how to login a website with verify code. One way I learnt is to use cookies. So I had a try. But I realised a problem.
For example, I want to use request.session to get url:www.lovetvshow.com
And I can get all the html text, but when I was trying to convert it to Json, it failed. It always shows "[ValueError] No JSON object could be decoded". But I have already had the text. Why is it no json object?

```
session = requests.session()
login_data = {'email': email, 'password': password}
header = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36',
    'Host': 'www.lovetvshow.com'
}
# r = session.post('http://www.renren.com/', data=login_data, headers=header)
r = session.get('http://www.lovetvshow.com/',headers=header)
print r
print r.json()
```

This will yield:

```
<Response [200]>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Hao/PycharmProjects/WebSpiderTutorial1/WebSpiderTutorial1.py", line 128, in <module>
    requests_session, requests_cookies = create_session()
  File "C:/Users/Hao/PycharmProjects/WebSpiderTutorial1/WebSpiderTutorial1.py", line 104, in create_session
    print r.json()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 892, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 383, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Any suggestions? Thanks a head.

Comment: What makes you think there's JSON to be decoded there? You've accessed the home page of a website, the response is in HTML.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your reply. Ya I have been thinking why this problem happened. And I also think that there may not be a json object to be converted. The reason I wrote r.json() is that, I saw in a tutorial and the program opens a url and then he could convert response r to a json object. When I saw that, I thought every response could be converted to json object. But thanks a lot for helping

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure there is JSON to be decoded. Check the complete text using 
print `print r.text` . And look for your json

Comment: Ya thanks for your helping guhkun. I saw in a tutorial program. The program uses post to get a response and then converts the response to json object to handle verify code issues. I thought we could always do so. Thank you